# How is this powerful vomit effect scene achieved?

Tags: effects, hubie-halloween

At the beginning of the movie [Hubie Halloween (2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10682266/), the character "Hubie", played by Adam Sandler, has an extremely powerful throw up. How is this effect achieved?

[image: Hubie Halloween vomit scene]

Comment: A wire by the side of his face